# SQL conditional filter

Tags: sql, postgresql, filter, subquery, conditional-statements

I have the data in the following format:

```
ID  Val
1   abc
1   xyz
2   abc
3   abc
3   pqr
3   xyz
4   abc
```

Now, I want IDs that do not have any other value than 'abc'. This would mean that I need IDs 2,4 ONLY. 1,3 have abc as well as other 2 values. The output should look like

```
ID  Val
2   abc
4   abc
```

I tried:

```
SELECT ID, Val from
Table
WHERE Val = 'abc'
AND Val != 'xyz'
AND Val != 'pqr'
```

This gives me all the IDs.
Any thoughts?
Please help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply count the rows that fulfill this certain criterium in a subquery.

```
SELECT ID, Val from
Table T1
WHERE T1.Val = 'abc'
AND 1 = (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Table T2 WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID)
```

or, alternatively

```
SELECT ID, Val from
Table T1
WHERE T1.Val = 'abc'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table T2 WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID AND T2.Value != 'abc')
```

Comment: Why did you use two table? There is no mention of data in two table in the question.

Comment: It is the same table (Table) joined. That's the trick. Simply try it.

Comment: nice apporach..This should be the accepted answer :)

Comment: THIS IS JUST PERFECT!!!
Thanks a lot Grzegorz Górkiewicz !!

Just a curiosity, are there any resources you would recommend to improve SQL skills??

Comment: Staying Classy !! :D


Noone can deny that...!! Thanks a lot ! :)
Will keep up the progress ! : )

Comment: You may also want to check out the Celko classic's https://www.amazon.com/Joe-Celko/e/B000ARBFVQ/ref=dp_byline_cont_book_1.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this with a simple `group by` and `having`:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having min(val) = max(val) and min(val) = 'abc';
```

This seems like the simplest approach to me.